# Android Video on Chromebook dropping First Few Frames

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have an app which plays a lot of video files. It's been all good on every phone and tablet I've tested on. I just tested on an Acer Chromebook and the first few frames (maybe up to a 1/4 second) are being dropped on all video files, so the video appears to start just slightly beyond 0. Some of the videos have audio that starts immediately and so it's obvious to the user that the video is clipped at the start. I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this issue, maybe on a Chromebook or other device and if there is some simple way to deal with it?

There is absolutely nothing fancy about my code. I'm using VideoView, preload the video with setVideoURI(), then call videoView.start() on a button press.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem only appears if I make a call to seek(0). So rather than doing that to replay the video I have to load the video each time it's requested. That workaround resolves the problem.